# What is known about$\sum\limits_{p\text{ prime}} \frac{1}{p^2-1}$?

Tags: analysis, number-theory, reference-request

Are there some known results for $\sum\limits_{p\text{ prime}} \dfrac{1}{p^2-1}$? I wasn't able to find anything about this sum in the internet or in my books!

Comment: What kind of result are you looking for?

Comment: If the real part of $s$ is greater than one, the prime zeta function is defined by the series $\sum p^{-s}$ for prime $p$. To my knowledge, no closed form has been found for any values of the prime zeta function. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_zeta_function

Comment: One known result about this is that it converges.  That is trivial, by a comparison test with a familiar series.

Comment: Since it is $\sum_{p} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{p^{2k}} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_p \frac{1}{p^{2k}}$ it is the sum of the even prime zeta functions. It certainly has an easy upper bound of $\zeta(2)-1$.